# bitpay integration and callback

Tags: api, bitcoin

Я делаю интеграцию сайта из платежкой Bitpay и суть в том что не приходит callback ответ от сервера когда инвойс оплачивается.
Опишу как я это делаю:
1. зарегистрировался на сайте test.bitpay.com (тестовый сайт)
2. завел себе два тестовых кошелька, один из них привязал к bitpay, на второй зачислил биткоинты.
3. на сайте генерю инвойс, при етом при формировании инвойса проставляю адрес notificationUrl https://example.com/bitpay/ipn куда должен идти коллбек.
4. оплачиваю коллбек
5. смотрю логи обращений - их нет(

В чем сдесь может быть причина "фейла"?

UPD: сайт из https and method use POST

UPD: залил ролик из проблемой, так как до сих пор еще не решил задачу https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s75r6hrfBCc&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Example.com/bitpay/ipn - это адрес вашего сервера, куда будет идти вызов POST от BitPay. Само собой вы его не получите так как это врядли ваш домен.

Comment: ))) да дейстительно не мой) вам пожет как то если я в вопросе укажу действительный адрес? я его не указываю что бы имя сайта не "светилось" на программерских форумах.

Comment: я думаю может не идет потому что использую тестовый енваермент, или хз уже. https://bitpay.com/downloads/bitpayApi.pdf 13 page

Comment: Если вы его указываете правильно, попробуйте сконструировать тестовый POST запрос на этот адрес с якобы от BitPay (содержимое не важно) и проверить что он приходит правильно.

Comment: делал запросы от PostMan - они логируются (я через монолог все что приходит на коллбек бросаю в логи)

Comment: Проблем с сертификатом нет, проверяли?

Comment: а как можно проверить? вроде сгенерил чезер lets Encrypted, настроили сервак, пишет защищено зеленым и браузер не матерится

Comment: Ну если редиректа нет с http на https тогда остаётся только запрашивать в техподдержке или проверять ответы в BitPay

Comment: добавил в основное описание видео что и как делаю

Comment: Проверили права на php файл как указали в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849488/bitpay-payment-callback-not-working ? Если не получается до сих пор, попробуйте сервис наподобие https://requestb.in, возможно что-то с вашим доменом.

Comment: на сервак все через ftp забрасываю (права все абсолютно под пользователем ftp) тоесть проблем не должно быть в принципе. Для проверки кто обращается скидываю в логи все, урл который обозначил для коллбека пробывал из постмана использывать - логи писались.

Comment: стопэ, так логи ж пишутся от других реквестов - значит проблем из доступом нет

Comment: Значит действительно надо писать в техподдержку BitPay